# Dell Laptop not powering on

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1564 laptop. It was working fine until yesterday night. Today morning when I tried powering up, the display was **blank**. It was *blank*, not *black*, i.e, it looked as if the laptop was off, the display does not light up at all. The power light stays on, the hard drive light turns on for a second and then turns off and stays off. I can hear the fans running. I tried connecting to an external display. I tried resetting CMOS(BIOS) by removing and reinserting CMOS cell. I tried reinserting RAM sticks. Nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Update: Just tested screen using *LCD BIST(D + Power)*, got solid colors flashing, screen is working fine. So why is the display blank??

Comment: A) what OS are you running? B) did you try to boot from an external source (USB stick, CDRom etc) c) from your description it seems you can access the BIOS?

Comment: A) My laptop is dual-booted running Win10 and Ubuntu 15.10. B) I can't boot from an external source as my laptop screen is blank, I can't select the external source. C) No, I can't excess the BIOS, screen is completely blank, just like it would be when the computer is turned off..

Comment: If you cannot boot see/boot bios I would assume that your connection between the GPU and the screen is broken

Comment: What about Fn + Power button? http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/266435?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04 & http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN127732/en

Comment: Tried that.. Nothing happens